# where do I point my browser to watch for changes when I run npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to use npm to watch for changes in my project and see them reflected in my browser. I'm essentially trying to use [this](https://github.com/keithamus/npm-scripts-example/tree/master) implementation of npm but I've modified the code a bit to run when I put `npm run build:watch` in my terminal. Here is what gets output in my terminal when I run that command:

```
> nodemon -q -w assets/ --ext "." --exec "npm run build"


> npm-scripts-example@1.0.0 prebuild
> npm run clean -s


> npm-scripts-example@1.0.0 build
> npm run build:scripts -s && npm run build:styles -s && npm run build:markup -s
```

As you can see above, everything seems to be running as intended. My question is: where do I point my browser to see my project run? I tried localhost:3000 because it seems like that's the default and I've tried a bunch of other ports on my localhost but nothing loads.

Comment: Don't confuse `npm` with `npm-scripts-example`

Answer (score 0):

Look at what the commands you are running actually do:

> ```
> "build": "npm run build:scripts -s && npm run build:styles -s && npm run build:markup -s",
> "build:scripts": "browserify -d assets/scripts/main.js -p [minifyify --compressPath . --map main.js.map --output dist/main.js.map] | hashmark -n dist/main.js -s -l 8 -m assets.json \"dist/{name}{hash}{ext}\"",
> "build:styles": "stylus assets/styles/main.styl -m -o dist/ && hashmark -s -l 8 -m assets.json dist/main.css \"dist/{name}{hash}{ext}\"",
> "build:markup": "jade assets/markup/index.jade --obj assets.json -o dist",
> ```

Specifically look up what all the scripts do (i.e. `browserify`, `stylus` and `jade`.

The documentation tell you what the command line flags mean.

The command line flags tell you where they are putting their output.

(The `dist` directory).